# How do I use a Google Cloud Function to add an ip to the authorized networks of a Cloud SQL instance?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

As the title says I have a gcp sql instance and want to add an ip to it's list of authorized networks using a cloud functions (in Python). According to https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ip#rest I can use this rest call:

```
curl -X PATCH \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth print-access-token) \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
-d @request.json \
https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/project-id/instances/instance-id
```

So my idea would be to use requests to make this call from within the cloud function. However, I do not know how to get the result of `gcloud auth print-access-token` in the cloud function.

Comment: You need to fetch the access token for the cloud function's service account from the metadata server or use an API that can do that for you.  See [this page](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Cloud SQL Admin API client library for Python, which will use the default service account credentials to include this authorization token for you. Check out the [Client libraries and sample code](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/libraries#python) page for more info.

Alternatively, if you prefer to manually create the requests, you can use an Oauth 2.0 token. The [Authorizing requests](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/how-tos/authorizing) page has more information for how to create these.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of python code to make an authorized request (here a GET version. customize it with the verb that you want)

```
    from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession
    from google.oauth2 import service_account
    import google.auth

    base_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/'

    credentials, project_id = google.auth.default(scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])
    project_id = 'yourProjectID'
    instance_id = 'yourInstanceID'
    
    authed_session = AuthorizedSession(credentials)
    response = authed_session.request('GET', f'{base_url}{project_id}/instances/{instance_id}')
    print(response.json())
```